# jqGrid and CodeIgniter Problem

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter, jqgrid

I have problem with loading my jqGrid. It just loads two parallel lines, and shows "Loading..." above them.
This is my controller:

```
function grid()
{
    $var['grid'] = $this->Uom_model->select();
         $i = 0;
         foreach($var['grid'] as $row) 
         {
            $response->rows[$i]['id']=$row->id;
            $response->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row->id,$row->uname);
            $i++;
         }
   echo json_encode($response);


}
```

This is my View:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    jQuery("#list27").jqGrid({
           url:'<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/uom/grid',
           datatype: "json",
           mtype: "post",
           height: 250,
           width: 450,
           colNames:['ID','Unit of Measure'],
           colModel:[
                  {name:'id',index:'id', width:65},
                  {name:'uname',index:'uname'}
              ],
           rowNum:50,
           rowTotal: 2000,
           rowList : [20,30,50],
           loadonce:true,
           rownumbers: true,
           rownumWidth: 40,
           gridview: true,
           pager: '#pager27',
           viewrecords: true,
           sortorder: "asc",
           caption: "Loading data from server at once"    
       });
});
```

The JSON output if I run only the function "grid" from the controller is:

```
{"rows":[{"id":"1","cell":["1","grams"]},{"id":"2","cell":["2","hour"]},{"id":"3","cell":["3","kilo"]},{"id":"4","cell":["4","liter"]},{"id":"5","cell":["5","pcs"]}]}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you used Firebug to check what your ajax process is sending/getting back? Might be just a simple JS issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not reproduce your problem, but the grid from my test (see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Marko.htm)) have wrong row numbers. Using `jsonReader`

```
jsonReader: {
    page: function (obj) { return 1; },
    total: function (obj) { return 1; },
    records: function (obj) { return obj.rows.length; }
}
```

one can solve the problem: see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Marko1.htm).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Really appreciate it. I tested with FireBug, and there is no ajax request being sent/or received from my view to my controller (grid).

Comment: @Marko: Why you use `<?php echo base_url();?>` in the url? If you will try to access another site or at least another ip port on the same web server you will have [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) problem. If you **realy** need access another site your server should support JSONP and you should use '&jsonCallback=?' as the part of the url.

Comment: Thank you Oleg again for the help. Is it OK to use <?php echo site_url('uom/grid/');?>

Btw, I was unable to create the grid because I didn't include: jQuery.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true; , in my header.